# Git and character casing woes - OSX

Tags: git, github

We have a repo in which files had been committed with a lower case filename.  I have updated the files in question in finder and then committed, however, the file often changes case.  This can has been due to out of sync merge requests from other developers but we have been trying to resolve the issue with no success.

We have now created a .gitconfig file setting ignorecase to false, but the file appears to be getting ignored.  Could anyone suggest how this could be resolved as it is driving us all round the bend!

Answer (score 0):

Make a case-sensitive disk image using Disk Utility, then clone your repo there, fix the case bugs, and commit.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by deleting the duplicate files (lowercase) on all branches from the github users interface.  We then had all developers clone a fresh version of the repo, although a a hard reset could have done the job